# It's a question of the TOEIC test

Tags: objects, double-possessives

Which is the correct answer?

> The president of Girou Electronics stated that the financial performance of the company was a personal responsibility of ...
>
> 1. his
> 2. himself
> 3. he
> 4. him

Comment: [LINK](https://able2know.org/topic/221658-1) According to this link, 1 is correct.

Answer (score 3):

1 is correct - it is "a personal responsibility of his". This - the construction `(a/the/some/etc...) NOUN of POSSESSIVE` -  is, as the [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/PossessivesandAttributives/faq0006.html) calls it, a "double genitive," and it's a common possessive idiom in English. Compare, for instance, the lines:

> Ah we can dance if we want to, we can leave your friends behind
>   Cause your friends don't dance and if they don't dance
>   Well **they're no friends of mine**

from the classic song "The Safety Dance" by Men Without Hats, for one of many, many examples of this sort of usage.

Comment: For the life of *me*, I think claiming that we must (or even just should) always use *double genitives* is probably misleading. For example, even though it's true that *the responsibility of his* is more idiomatic than *of him*, I think it sounds more natural to say *(this is) the responsibility of his family*, *of his children*, etc. than *of his family's*, *of his children's*, etc.

Answer (score -1):

If I had to pick one of the choices for the example sentence, I would choose option #2; the word 'himself'.

This sentence could be re-written into a clearer sentence. I would have used the sentence: "The president of Girou Electronics stated that the financial performance of the company was his personal responsibility".

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer for it is number 4,that is,him. This fits in the context.

> The president of Girou Electronics stated that the financial performance of the company was personal responsibility of him.